# How does Ruby namespace the parent class of a nested class

Tags: ruby, namespaces, ruby-2.0, pundit

While working with the Ruby gem Pundit, I realized I was unsure of the way some namespacing works within Ruby and I do not like mysteries/uncertainties in my mind.

Pundit suggests you set up an `application_policy.rb` as so:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope
     .
     .
     .
  end
end
```

What actually is happening inside of the class doesn't matter, just the structure of the classes do.

Then you specify a policy for a  particular resource that inherits from `ApplicationPolicy`, say `post_policy.rb` as so:

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
  end
end
```

My general question is, inside my `PostPolicy`, when I declare that `Scope < Scope`, what does the parent `Scope` refer to? Does it automatically get namespaced within the parent of the outer class? So is it essentially the same as inheriting from `ApplicationPolicy::Scope`? I am having trouble finding a way to answer this on my own, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

You are right on both counts. You can check it with [`Class#ancestors`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) :

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope
  end
end

class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
  end
end

p PostPolicy::Scope.ancestors
#=> [PostPolicy::Scope, ApplicationPolicy::Scope, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

## Equivalent code

The above code is exactly the same as :

```
class ApplicationPolicy
end

class ApplicationPolicy::Scope
end

class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
end

class PostPolicy::Scope < ApplicationPolicy::Scope
end

p PostPolicy::Scope.ancestors
#=> [PostPolicy::Scope, ApplicationPolicy::Scope, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Note that `PostPolicy::Scope` doesn't inherit from `PostPolicy`. They are independant classes, the former just happens to be defined in the namespace of the latter.

## Another way to check

```
class A
  class Scope
  end
end

class B < A
  class Scope < Scope
  end
end

class C
  class Scope < Scope
  end
end
```

fails with :

```
namespace.rb:26:in `<class:C>': uninitialized constant C::Scope (NameError)
    from namespace.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

It means that `Scope` must come from `A` namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, and sorry for taking a while to respond. Your answer was awesome an super thorough! Thank you. For some reason, the shorthand of `class Scope < Scope` really referring to `ApplicationPolicy::Scope` doesn't seem natural to me or what I would expect, but I guess it's just the way it is and at least now I understand!

Comment: One thing that's interesting and slightly confusing is the following scenario:

[1] pry(main)> class C1
[1] pry(main)* end
=> nil
[2] pry(main)> class C2 < C1
[2] pry(main)*   class Nested < Nested
[2] pry(main)*   end
[2] pry(main)* end
NameError: uninitialized constant C2::Nested
from (pry):4:in `<class:C2>'
[3] pry(main)>

Comment: By not defining `C1::Nested`, the error message is `NameError: uninitialized constant C2::Nested`.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree the syntax is a bit too convoluted. I wouldn't use it for anything that should be read by other people.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite easy to get youself:

```
class C1; class Nested; end; end
class C2<C1; class Nested<Nested; end; end

C2::Nested.ancestors
#⇒ [
#  [0] C2::Nested < C1::Nested,
#  [1] C1::Nested < Object,
#  [2] Object < BasicObject,
#  [3] PP::ObjectMixin,
#  [4] Kernel,
#  [5] BasicObject
# ]
```

So, yes, It’s implicitly resolved to `ApplicationPolicy::Scope`.

Comment: Appreciate you showing how you determined it, thanks!

Comment: One thing that's interesting and slightly confusing is the following scenario: [1] pry(main)> class C1 [1] pry(main)* end => nil [2] pry(main)> class C2 < C1 [2] pry(main)* class Nested < Nested [2] pry(main)* end [2] pry(main)* end NameError: uninitialized constant C2::Nested from (pry):4:in `<class:C2>' [3] pry(main)>

Comment: So, by not defining C1::Nested, the error message is NameError: uninitialized constant C2::Nested, does this make sense to you?